# can't create and generate typeorm migration

Tags: postgresql, migration, nestjs, typeorm

i want to do generate for entity which i have created to database using typeorm

but i get an error like this

Generates a new migration file with sql needs to be executed to update schema
Not enough non-option arguments: got 0, need at least 1
Note: This command was run via npm module 'win-node-env'
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! crud_api_reuse@0.0.1 typeorm: `NODE_ENV=migration ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js -f --config ./src/config/ormconfig.ts "migration:generate" "--name" "create_table_user"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the crud_api_reuse@0.0.1 typeorm script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! C:\Users\jojo\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\logs\2022-11-13T12_28_28_622Z-debug.log

this is my project structure
[image]

inside my ormconfig.ts file like this

`

```
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
import { TypeOrmModuleOptions } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
dotenv.config();
const dir = process.env.NODE_ENV == 'migration' ? 'src' : 'dist';
export default <TypeOrmModuleOptions>{
  type: process.env.DATABASE_CONNECTION,
  host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
  port: Number(process.env.DATABASE_PORT),
  username: process.env.DATABASE_USERNAME,
  password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.DATABASE_NAME,
  entities: [`${dir}/**/*.entity.{js,ts}`],
  migrations: [`${dir}/models/migrations/*.{js,ts}`],
  seeds: [`${dir}/models/migrations/seeds/*.seed.{js,ts}`],
  factories: [`${dir}/models/migrations/seeds/factories/*.factory.{js,ts}`],
  cli: {
    migrationsDir: `${dir}/models/migrations`,
    entitiesDir: `${dir}/models/entities`,
    seedersDir: `${dir}/models/migrations/seeds`,
    factoriesDir: `${dir}/models/migrations/seeds/factories`,
  },
  synchronize: false,
  migrationsRun: false,
};
```

`

and the script that I created in the package.json file is like this
`

```
"typeorm": "NODE_ENV=migration ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js -f --config ./src/config/ormconfig.ts",
    "typeorm:migration:generate": "npm run typeorm migration:generate -- --name",
    "typeorm:migration:create": "npm run typeorm migration:create -- --name",
    "typeorm:migration:run": "npm run typeorm migration:run",
    "typeorm:migration:revert": "npm run typeorm migration:revert",
    "typeorm:seed": "NODE_ENV=migration ts-node ./node_modules/typeorm-seeding/dist/cli.js --configName ./src/config/ormconfig.ts",
    "typeorm:seed:run": "npm run typeorm:seed seed",
    "typeorm:schema:drop": "ts-node ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js schema:drop"
```

`

but when I try to migrate, I get an error like the one above
so what should I do to be able to migrate?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem in your command to run migration missing some args.
Have you built before running new migration?
what is your typeorm version you're using?
in my case use 0.2.45:

my package.json script:[image]

my command to create new migration base on entity (remember build first):

```
npm run migration:generate your_migration_name
```

try it!